# Does the following limit exists and equals 0?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider the two variables limit:
$$ \lim_{\substack{n\to\infty\\\epsilon\to 0}}\frac{\log n}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}\cdot\log\left(n\epsilon\right)}$$

Does the limit exist, and is it $0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $m=1/\epsilon$.  We thus have
$$\lim_{m,n\to\infty} {1\over m}\cdot{\log n\over \log n-\log m}$$
There are divisions by zero then when $m=n$ even when both are small, not a good sign.  On the other hand, if $m=xn$ with $x>0$ fixed we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over 2n}\cdot{\log n\over \log n-\log x-\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} {-1\over 2n}\cdot{\log n\over \log x}=0$$
When $m=n+1$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {-1\over n+1}\cdot{\log n\over \log (n+1)-\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} {-1\over n+1}\cdot{\log n\over \log (n(1+1/n))-\log n}$$
which also tends to infinity because $\log(1+1/n)\approx 1/n$ for $n$ large.  In light of all this, the limit does not exist.